# Is there any way to open a ".dat" repository file from Visual Age for Java?

Tags: java, ide

I'm currently trying to recover some old code that was developed using IBM Visual Age for Java. Unfortunately I do not have an installation anymore, and the only thing I have is just a ".dat" file containing the repository.

Is there any way to get my code back? Otherwise, is there any way to get an old Visual Age for Java install so that I can try to recover my code directly?

Comment: @mre just wrong.  But made me laugh

Comment: @Atreys, I couldn't resist :)

Comment: I will ask my english friends around to comment because I'm not gettin it. Anyway, I'm changing the original question in order to remove the offending part

Answer (score 1):

It appears that IBM.com does not have the Visual Age Developer Domain online anymore, and hence not the trial downloads which would have been perfect for your purpose.

I would suggest that you call your local IBM branch, and explain your problem and ask if you can get access to one of the old distributions to see if your problem can be fixed.

If not, you might consider decompiling the current class/jar files before looking into purchasing from IBM or finding an old copy on ebay or similar.